# What is the difference between preferredLocalization and preferredLanguage?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Definition of `[NSLocale preferredLanguages]` according to the documentations:

> The user's language preference order as an array of NSString objects, each of which is a canonicalized IETF BCP 47 language identifier.

Definition of `[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations]`:

> An array of NSString objects, each of which identifies the a localization in the receiver’s bundle. The languages are in the preferred order.

I really don't get what the difference is. Which one should be one using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe language is just language, but locale implies a great deal more (e.g. calendar/date computations, currency, number formatting, etc). The [Locales Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFLocales/Articles/CFLocaleConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002240-CJBDBHCB) is a short read, a great place to start.

More specifically, `+preferredLocalizations`, being a bundle resource, is a component of an app itself, configurable during app design, whereas `+preferredLanguages`, coming from `NSLocale` (btw it's a class method, not an object method) represents the system-level preferences of the user.

Therefore, `+preferredLocalizations` provides the language the app is actually running in whereas `+preferredLanguages` provides the language the user prefers their apps to run in (even if the apps don't yet support it).

Comment: Thanks, I've just realised that it was a class method :) I'm reading that up, cheers.